# WAMP server over internet

Tags: wamp, portforwarding

I want my WAMP server to be available on internet. How do I do that? I was told, that one option is to use port forwording, I did this 
http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Dlink/DSL-2642B/defaultguide.htm

But, it didnt work. I cannot access my site from public ip. Can anyone help me, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

you still need to make your wamp server as a virtual host in your network after getting a static IP.

in your httpd file add the following:

```
<VirtualHost yourlocalIP 127.0.0.1> 
ServerName something.loc    //for use locally and not a domain name 
ServerAlias www*.something.loc //for use locally and not a domain name
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www" 
<Directory "C:/wamp/www"> 
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks +Includes +ExecCGI 
AllowOverride None 
Order allow,deny 
Allow from all 
</Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

and don't forget to make the required modifications in your host file located in `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc`

so when the router do the ip forwarding for you, your localhost knows what to do. 
you might also need to specify the port with yourLocalIP.

Comment: I was afraid to use ur solution, but i guess, i am left with no choice. I tried adding ur lines in httpd but localhost didnt work anymore after adding ur lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Check whether WAMP server is currently running or not (mainly the apache webserver which accepts the incoming connections on port 80).You can check this most of the time by verifying the colour of wampserver icon in system tray.If its green, means its all OK.Still open cmd and telnet to port 80 to check whether apache is running or not.

2.)Are you behind a LAN(you are using a router)or directly connected to the internet ? If former is true then you have to enable port forwarding in your router (which u have done as you said)

3.) What ip address you are typing in your browser's address bar to access your WAMP server from external machine ? I hope its not your LAN address(192.168.1.4). It has to be a WAN ip(the one which you see going to http://whatismyip.com)

4.)Last but not least check whether its not blocked in your windows firewall

Comment: I have changed listening port of wamp to 1342. And yes it is online.

Comment: I am behind the LAN and thats y, I am using port forwarding.

Comment: I can access my wamp pages with localhost:1342, 127.0.0.1:1342 and my static ip 192.168.1.5:1342 but not with public ip:1342.

Comment: Firewall was enabled. I disabled it, But still it doesnt work.

Comment: I am sure then its windows firewall issue.Since you have changed apache port you may need to reconfigure windows firewall to accept incoming request on port 1342
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-vista/Open-a-port-in-Windows-Firewall

Comment: I have completely turned off firewall, still it doesnt work. I am using windows 8 now.

Comment: I used http://www.canyouseeme.org/ to check my port seen from outside, it turns positive for me.

Comment: I think there is some fault in your port forwarding setup ?

Comment: Well, I followed all steps according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084052/how-do-i-forward-my-port-for-wamp-and-iis . I guess that is not the problem.